# A person who is always in front of the computer

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I have a friend who is always in front of the computer and spends a great amount of time surfing the internet or doing anything related to the computer.

How can you describe this person in a word?

Comment: The question is too ambiguous to know the intended meaning.  What aspect are you trying to capture?  The sedentary nature? Addiction to the activity? Reliance on a computer as a tool?  Reliance on the content they view? Their proficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use **"mouse potato"** which [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouse%20potato):

> a person who spends a great deal of time using a computer

Comment: I have never heard that ever

Comment: I haven't either but I love it

Answer (score 0):

One could use "compuholic" to express the addiction aspect. Or "Internet addict". The word "compuholic" is of course formed by analogy with "alcoholic". Many coinages with the "-holic" ending have already been made to indicate beeing addicted to some specific thing.

Answer (score -1):

Informally, people would probably refer to such a person as a **geek** or **nerd**